# Game Wont start if joypad is plugged in

Tags: windows, controller

I have just gotten a speedlink Strike NX control pad to use on an XP PC for gta san andreas.

I plugged in the controller, the found new hardware wizard failed and still keeps nagging me when I plug it in. However I downloaded the driver setup tool from this [source](http://www.speedlink.com/?p=3&cat=4132&pid=38923&paus=2&PHPSESSID=7aaae534fdc569dd1ee1e46f280430e6)

I clicked setup.exe and then in control panel>game controllers I am able to see the devices and when I test it it works fine, using the tester that is part of control panel>game controllers.

I then click to open grand theft auto san andreas, I get a spinning disk icon then an hourglass icon then nothing happnes. I see it in task manager but it then closes  adter the hourglass has dissapeared.

I unplug the game controller, click to run the game again and the game shows up fine.

However when plugged in the controller, nothing happnes. I have made sure that 'joypad' is selected in the games settings menu but no luck. I expect that is because the controller must be plugged in before starting the game.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Far as I know, this game is not "open source".  Therefore, the best people on the planet to troubleshoot GTA San Andreas's actions will be the company that created and supports the game.  You may want to try some other things (using joystick in other games; using other joysticks) to see how well they work/not, as such details may be interesting to the support people who try to help with this.

Comment: The joy pad works in another game called Lego worlds. I don't think rock star support GTA San Andreas since its such an old game